# ERROR: Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I am building an application in React. My problem is that if I navigate to the route '/factura/api/invoices/${invoiceId}' and press the edit button, it should send the information to the MongoDB database and return that everything is fine, but when I do it, I get the following error.

```
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/auth/gssapi.js:4:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./pages/facturas/api/edit/[invoiceId]/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

I am not sure why I am receiving this error. This is my first part of the code located in the '/facturas/edit/[invoiceId]' folder:

```
const updateInvoice = async (invoiceId, status) => {
        try {

            const res = await fetch(`/facturas/api/edit/${invoiceId}`, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    senderStreet: senderStreet,
                    senderCity: senderCity,
                    senderPostalCode: senderPostalCode,
                    senderCountry: senderCountry,
                    clientName: clientName,
                    clientEmail: clientEmail,
                    clientStreet: clientStreet,
                    clientCity: clientCity,
                    clientPostalCode: clientPostalCode,
                    clientCountry: clientCountry,
                    description: description,
                    createdAt: createdAt,
                    paymentDue: createdAt,
                    paymentTerms: paymentTerms,
                    status: status,
                    items: items,
                    total: totalAmount
                })
            })

            const data = await res.json()

            router.push(`/facturas/invoices/${invoiceId}`)
            toast.success(data.message)

        } catch (error) {
            toast.error("Something is wrong")
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

And this is the second part of the code in the file located in the API folder:

```
import { MongoClient, ObjectId } from "mongodb";

async function handler(req, res) {
  const { invoiceId } = req.query;
  const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb+srv://test:test@cluster0.uusfifl.mongodb.net/invoices?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true });
  
  const db = client.db();
  const collection = db.collection("allInvoices");

  if (req.method === "PUT") {
    await collection.updateOne(
      {
        _id: ObjectId(invoiceId),
      },
      {
        $set: {
          senderAddress: {
            street: req.body.senderStreet,
            city: req.body.senderCity,
            postalCode: req.body.senderPostalCode,
            country: req.body.senderCountry,
          },
          clientName: req.body.clientName,
          clientEmail: req.body.clientEmail,
          clientAddress: {
            street: req.body.clientStreet,
            city: req.body.clientCity,
            postalCode: req.body.clientPostalCode,
            country: req.body.clientCountry,
          },
          createdAt: req.body.createdAt,
          paymentDue: req.body.createdAt,
          paymentTerms: req.body.paymentTerms,
          description: req.body.description,
          status: req.body.status,
          items: req.body.items,
          total: req.body.total,
        },
      }
    );

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Invoice updated successfully" });
  }

  client.close();
}

export default handler;
```

And here are all the files that I have used, in case you want to see them:

https://github.com/Fukene/tarea_database

Thanks.

I tried to reinstall MongoDB again. I checked that the routes were correct and verified that the MongoDB credentials information were correct. And everything seems to be fine. I still don't know what the problem is.

The confusing thing is that it was working well until I changed the files in folders. I suppose the problem is that the route to some file is wrong, but I haven't found where the problem is.

**Edit**

I found some posts that say I should move my folders to be directly in the /pages folder, and when I do that my code works perfectly. Why? It's a novice question, but I don't understand how to differentiate what is acting as frontend and what as backend.

Comment: What is your node version? `node -v`

Comment: node version v19.3.0

Comment: My gues would be you have a server-side only import on client side. In Nextjs you have to remove them if they are not used in getServerSideProps for example.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just starting to learn about programming, would you like to clarify how I can solve it? I don't quite understand what solution you propose. Also thank you very much for your answer. It's a relief to have options

Comment: Were there any errors when you ran `npm install mongodb`?

Comment: No, the following message appears without any error in the console:
`up to date, audited 115 packages in 1s`
`6 packages are looking for funding`
`run npm fund for details`
But when I run the program again, the same problem continues to appear.

Comment: @LuisDavidFuqueneCharry it's not an error